# Write definition for specific file

Tags: typescript

I want to write definition for specific file, for example I have these files:

[image: Files]

Where `style.less` is css module and I want write definition for this file to have autocomplete. All the definitions must be in `infa.d.ts`.

In `some.ts` I have

```
import * as s from './style.less';
```

and definition in `infa.d.ts`

```
declare module 'one/style.less' {

}
```

TypeScript tells that it cannot find module but the declaration points to correct file.

If I change in `some.ts` import to

```
import * as s from 'one/style.less';
```

Everything works, but imagine if the path will be longer or if I move the folder to another place and in this case I will have to change the path.

Another option is that I can put the definition along with the less file

[image: Files]

But this is not for me because there will be a lot of files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported.

An ambient module cannot specify a relative path.

I've tried a number of workarounds but the only one that allows specifying a relative path in the import module specifier is to either create a `.d.ts` file for each file, as you describe in detail, or to specify a full wildcard path.

```
declare module "*.less" {
  declare const content: string;
  export default content; // or export = content for CommonJS
}
```

Then you can import from any **.less** file but go to definition will annoyingly take you to the ambient declaration above.
This provides no type safety and does not verify that the file exists but neither does any other approach. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615 where this feature is discussed.

If you use Visual Studio Code, there are a number of plugins that provide better navigation behavior which largely mitigates the got to definition annoyance but there is no verification of the file's presence and so the refactoring hazard remains. That said, I have not found this to honestly be a problem in practice so the wildcard approach largely meets my needs. It lets me get on with my day.

Comment: I have found some workaround using rootDir https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs

Comment: @aspirisen can you post that? I actually tried using rootDirs but I couldn't get it to work individual files, only for directories

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it using `rootDirs`.

[image]